# Add/remove Cake named URL parameter for a link

Tags: php, cakephp, friendly-url, url-modification

Using CakePHP 1.3 there are named parameters in the URL like `.../name:value/...`
These are used for example by pagination links `.../page:2/key:date/sort:desc/...`

How to generate links with `HtmlHelper::link()` adding/deleting such named parameters from the current URL?

Basically I want create links to add/remove/modify the `category:ID` named parameter in the current URL. It must not touch the URL, anchor, other named parameters, GET parameters in the URL.

Or how can I pass named parameters to `HtmlHelper::link()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`link('link text', array('controller' => 'something', 'action' => 'foo', 'category' => $id))`