# Filter results via selectbox!

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I filter Results by County,District,City with dropdown select.

Is there a way to do it in Cake way, because currently I'm doing it classic way, by passing Id to url, like:

```
/sort/county_id/1/district_id/5
```

But this is very bad hack, because I have to explode $this->here and not good thing. I don't know if there is uri class like in codeigniter, so I can play with $this->uri->segment().

In fact my problem is that I need to see if isset then pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered named parameters?

[Add/remove Cake named URL parameter for a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789894/add-remove-cake-named-url-parameter-for-a-link)

Comment: Interesting, but how to get params, I don't want to explode $this->here;

Comment: Named parameters can be read by the controller similar to any other parameter.  No need to explode here.